Getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: No provider for eF, when I hit the route whose component uses the service
I am getting NullInjectorError error when I am trying to use a service in my angular app. Below are my app.module.ts, admin.service.ts, angular.json(I have made a few changes to the default configs here) and package.json
app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminCrudComponent } from './components/admin-crud/admin-crud.component';
import { FormInputComponent } from './components/form-input/form-input.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
AdminCrudComponent,
FormInputComponent
 ],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
AngularEditorModule,
HttpClientModule,
 ],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }

admin.service.ts
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLConfig } from '../config/url.config';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AdminService {

constructor(private httpclient:HttpClient, private urlConfig: URLConfig) { }

createItem(item: any) {
const service = this.urlConfig.getConfig(environment.env);
const url = service.myApi+ 'items';
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
return this.httpclient.post(url, item, {headers: headers});
}
}

angular.json
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "version": 1,
 "newProjectRoot": "projects",
 "projects": {
 "client": {
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:application": {
      "strict": true
    }
  },
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/client",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "prod": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "uat": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.uat.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "prod"
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "prod": {
          "browserTarget": "client:build:prod"
        },
        "uat": {
          "browserTarget": "client:build:uat"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "uat"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "client:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}

package.json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "start:uat": "ng serve --configuration=uat",
  "start:prod": "ng serve --configuration=prod",
  "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
  "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
  "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
  "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
  "ngx-editor": "^13.0.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/cli": "~13.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
  "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}

Since I have made few config changes in angular.json that might be one of the reasons It is breaking.

Since I have made few config changes in angular.json that might be one of the reasons It is breaking - probably, what changes did you make?

@JaromandaX I had changed the "configurations",  "serve" properties where I specified uat and prod environment overriding the default configuration. Also I have made a few imports from the Bootstrap in the "styles" and "scripts" properties of angular.json.

@PrabhatBhargav please share the code of URLConfig try removing that and check if it solves the error

@PrabhatBhargav If possible stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens

Many thanks @NarenMurali As you suggested I removed URLConfig from service and It worked, I think the issue was there was no provider for the URLConfig dependency when I injected it in the constructor.

The code looks fine, try removing the URLConfig from the component, which might fix the error.

Else without removing you can define the URL config like so.
The provided in root, will ensure, the service is accessible by DI throughout the application.
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class URLConfig {
  getConfig() { ... }
}

